# Dynamic drop down list showing the times depending on current time

Tags: php, html

I currently have a drop down list which shows the timeslots and datepicker for the user to select a date. I am trying to make a dynamic timeslot which only shows the times according to the current time and date. For example if a user wants to make an appointment for 25/03/2015 , it should not display past times, but the current timings and times yet to come. However if they want to select a future date, it should show all the times.

```
        <select  name ="timeslot"> 
        <option value ="0"> Please select </option>
        <option value = "08:30" > 08:30 </option>
        <option value = "09:15" > 09:15 </option>
        <option value = "10:00" > 10:00 </option>
        <option value = "10:45" > 10:45 </option>
        <option value = "11:30" > 11:30 </option>
        <option value = "12:15" > 12:15 </option>
        <option value = "13:00" > 13:00 </option>
        <option value = "13:45" > 13:45 </option>
        <option value = "14:30" > 14:30 </option>
        <option value = "15:15" > 15:15 </option>
        <option value = "16:00" > 16:00 </option>
        <option value = "16:45" > 16:45 </option>
        <option value = "17:30" > 17:30 </option>
        </select>

        <p><input type="text" id="datepicker" name = "date" readonly = 'true'          
        placeholder = "Enter Date"></p>

        <script>
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
        dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'
          });
        </script>
```

Comment: at the moment i just have a datepicker to select date and drop down list to select time slots

Comment: As SO is not a free coding service, you should try by yourself and come back with a specific question about a specific point of your development. Now, you should use `javascript`/`jQuery` in order to dynamically change the content of your `select[name=timeslot]` according to the value of `#datepicker`.

Answer (score 0):

> below the code for time  dynamic drop-down

```
function creatTimeDropdown(){
        $hours = $minutes = $ampm = $optString='';
        $i=0;
        for( $i = 540; $i <= 1260; $i += 30){

                    $hours = floor($i / 60);
                    $minutes = $i % 60;
                    if ($minutes < 10){
                        $minutes = '0' . $minutes; // adding leading zero
                    }
                    $ampm = $hours % 24 < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';
                    $hours = $hours % 12;
                    if ($hours === 0){
                        $hours = 12;
                    }
                    $text =$hours.':'.$minutes.' '.$ampm;
                    $optString .='<option value="'.$i.'">'.$text.'</option>';



        }
        return $optString;
    }
```